# Putting Linux on a computer that can't recognize any hardware

Tags: linux, boot

I found an old computer with no OS, and I'm trying to get it working with Linux (I started with Fedora 19, then tried all sorts of Linux flavors), but I can't load anything on it because it doesn't recognize its original DVD drive, won't recognize any new ones, doesn't have an option for USB booting and nothing works when I preload an OS onto its drive.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: How old? Does it have any OS on it now? As is, we really have nothing to work on - throw us a bone here.

Comment: Even old computers can boot from the CD drive. Maybe you're putting a DVD media in a drive that only supports CDs? Or maybe its CD drive is damaged. The easiest solution might be to replace its CD drive.

Answer (score 1):

Try Plop Boot Manager. It is free software designed for use on old machines made before booting from USB was possible (or common, really). Just put it on a floppy (assuming you have a floppy-capable machine) and point your BIOS at the floppy instead of HD/CD/USB/whatever. It will then present you with a menu letting you choose which device to boot from. That is, unless you have a hardware issue that prevents your optical drives from showing up...

Answer (score 1):

Get a PCI or PCI-E network card and PXE boot a Debiain net-inst from a TFTP server.  Use TFTPD32 if you have a Windows system connected to your network and are in a pinch.  It's likely that your onboard NIC supports PXE boot as well.

Comment: PXE boot is good thing to try in this scenario (+1).

Answer (score 0):

I would try [Linux Zenwalk](http://www.zenwalk.org/). This is [Slackware](http://www.slackware.com/) based GNU/Linux distribution which can run on relatively old hardware:

Zenwalk GNU/Linux can run on any modern or semi-old computer (Zenwalk is optimized for the `i686` instruction set, but backward compatible with `i486`). These are the minimal hardware requirements to run Zenwalk in Xwindow mode, with correct performance (some lower configs work - ie : PII - , but might be slow) :

```
 Pentium III class processor
 256 Mb RAM
 4Gb HDD
```